# How do you get a reference to Server.MapPath from a utility file?

Tags: asp.net

I need a reference to Server.MapPath because I am using an api which needs it.

Even if there is a straight .net way to unzip a file I would still like to know what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is a part of http call

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()
```

if you do not have this Http Context alive, you can not have the Server.

One other way for the MapPath is to use the `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` and add your rest of your directory file

Comment: thank you, i was just about to mark myself as the right answer again http://www.seanmchugh.info/fixed.png